# Cannot extend unmapped class: Entity

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a base class called Entity:

```
public class Entity
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
}
```

Let's say I have a class called Customer:

```
public class Customer : Entity
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Now, using convention based mapping by code in NHibernate 3.3.1, I try the following:

```
public static class DataHelper
{
    private static HbmMapping GetMappings()
    {
        var mapper = new CustomModelMapper(typeof(Entity));           

        return mapper.CompileMappingFor(
            typeof(DataHelper).Assembly.GetExportedTypes()
                .Where(x => x.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Entity))));
    }
}
```

When I try to run my app, I get the error "Cannot extend unmapped class: Entity". I don't want to map the Entity class - it's just a base class for inheriting some common properties. How can I tell NHibernate to ignore the unmapped class? For reference, my CustomModelMapper class is listed below.

The code for my CustomModelMapper class is listed below for reference

```
internal class CustomModelMapper : ConventionModelMapper
{
    private const int DEFAULT_STRING_LENGTH = 100;
    private Type baseType;

    public CustomModelMapper(Type baseType)
    {
        this.baseType = baseType;
    }

    public CustomModelMapper()
    {
        SetupInspectors();
    }

    protected override void AppendDefaultEvents()
    {
        base.AppendDefaultEvents();
        BeforeMapClass += OnBeforeMapClass;
        BeforeMapProperty += OnBeforeMapProperty;
        BeforeMapManyToOne += OnBeforeMapManyToOne;
        BeforeMapBag += OnBeforeMapBag;
        BeforeMapList += OnBeforeMapList;
        BeforeMapSet += OnBeforeMapSet;
    }

    protected void OnBeforeMapClass(IModelInspector modelInspector, Type type, IClassAttributesMapper classCustomizer)
    {
        classCustomizer.Id(type.GetProperty("Id"), m => m.Generator(Generators.Native));
    }

    protected void OnBeforeMapProperty(IModelInspector modelInspector, PropertyPath member, IPropertyMapper propertyCustomizer)
    {
        if (member.LocalMember.GetPropertyOrFieldType().IsEnum)
        {
            var type = member.LocalMember.GetPropertyOrFieldType();
            var genericType = typeof(EnumStringType<>).MakeGenericType(type);
            propertyCustomizer.Type(genericType, null);
        }

        if (member.LocalMember.GetPropertyOrFieldType() == typeof(string))
            propertyCustomizer.Length(DEFAULT_STRING_LENGTH);
    }

    protected void OnBeforeMapManyToOne(IModelInspector modelInspector, PropertyPath member, IManyToOneMapper propertyCustomizer)
    {
        propertyCustomizer.Cascade(Cascade.All);
        propertyCustomizer.Fetch(FetchKind.Join);
        propertyCustomizer.Lazy(LazyRelation.NoLazy);

        propertyCustomizer.Index(string.Format("IX{0}{1}",
            member.GetContainerEntity(modelInspector).Name,
            member.LocalMember.Name));
    }

    protected void OnBeforeMapBag(IModelInspector modelInspector, PropertyPath member, IBagPropertiesMapper propertyCustomizer)
    {
        propertyCustomizer.Cascade(Cascade.All);
        propertyCustomizer.Lazy(CollectionLazy.Extra);
        propertyCustomizer.Fetch(CollectionFetchMode.Subselect);
    }

    protected void OnBeforeMapList(IModelInspector modelInspector, PropertyPath member, IListPropertiesMapper propertyCustomizer)
    {
        propertyCustomizer.Cascade(Cascade.All);
        propertyCustomizer.Lazy(CollectionLazy.Extra);
        propertyCustomizer.Fetch(CollectionFetchMode.Subselect);
    }

    protected void OnBeforeMapSet(IModelInspector modelInspector, PropertyPath member, ISetPropertiesMapper propertyCustomizer)
    {
        propertyCustomizer.Cascade(Cascade.All);
        propertyCustomizer.Lazy(CollectionLazy.Extra);
        propertyCustomizer.Fetch(CollectionFetchMode.Subselect);
    }

    protected void SetupInspectors()
    {
        IsRootEntity((type, declared) =>
        {
            return baseType.Equals(type.BaseType);
        });

        IsEntity((type, declared) =>
        {
            return baseType.IsAssignableFrom(type) && !type.IsInterface;
        });

        IsVersion((member, declared) =>
        {
            return
                member.Name == "Version" &&
                member.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property &&
                member.GetPropertyOrFieldType() == typeof(int);
        });


        IsBag((member, declared) =>
        {
            if (member.GetPropertyOrFieldType().IsGenericType)
                return IsGenericType(member, typeof(ICollection<>));

            return false;
        });

        IsList((member, declared) =>
        {
            if (member.GetPropertyOrFieldType().IsGenericType)
                return IsGenericType(member, typeof(IList<>));

            return false;
        });

        IsSet((member, declared) =>
        {
            if (member.GetPropertyOrFieldType().IsGenericType)
                return IsGenericType(member, typeof(ICG.ISet<>));

            return false;
        });
    }

    protected static bool IsGenericType(MemberInfo member, Type targetType)
    {
        var type = member.GetPropertyOrFieldType();
        var generics = type.GetGenericInterfaceTypeDefinitions();
        return generics.Contains(targetType);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is probably with your `IsEntity` convention. Currently, it will return true for `Entity` class itself. Just add another check:

```
IsEntity((type, declared) =>
{
    return baseType.IsAssignableFrom(type) && !type.IsInterface &&
           type != typeof(Entity); // <- skip Entity class
});
```

---

**Edit**

Also, you have two constructors in your `CustomModelMapper` class. One of them accepts base type, the other one is default and calls `SetupInspectors()`. As I can see, your default constructor will never be called, since you are calling the one that accepts the base type, and it doesn't call the default constructor...

And the consequence of that is... your `SetupInspectors()` method will also never be called.

Comment: Nope, I tried that, still get the same thing. It appears that the error is being thrown for entities that are collected via the GetExportedTypes() call that aren't explicitly declared via `mapper.Class<EntityClassNameHere>()` calls. These show up as JoinedSubClasses in the mapping document. If I add an empty mapping statement such as `mapper.Class<Customer>(map=>{})` for each class, the error goes away and each one is listed as a RootClass in the mapping document.

Comment: So I guess the question is, how can I ensure that NHibernate treats all entity classes as root classes?